SharePoint Calculated Column Multi Formulas
I am trying to add a calculated column based on other column value AbC123.
I want to use three formulas in the calculated column REPLACE, UPPER & LEFT.
I tried this formula
=UPPER(LEFT(Agent_Office,3))),Replace(Agent_Office,"A","E")
but it is not working.

Could you provide specific example for your requirement?
